# inconsistent plot between matplotlib and seaborn in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

i am trying to add errorbars using `plt.errorbar` to a `pointplot` in seaborn:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas
sns.set_style("white")

data = pandas.DataFrame({"x": [0.158, 0.209, 0.31, 0.4, 0.519],
                        "y": [0.13, 0.109, 0.129, 0.250, 1.10],
                        "s": [0.01]*5})

plt.figure()
sns.pointplot(x="x", y="y", data=data)
plt.errorbar(data["x"], data["y"], yerr=data["s"])
plt.show()
```

however the two plots look totally different even though the identical data is being plotted. what explains this and how can errorbars be added to a pointplot?

Comment: Are you sure `seaborn` is supposed to work like that? It seems like `matplotlib` and `seaborn` are competing for a single output window and are probably messing up each other's settings. If you plot the graphs separately, they seem to be correct.

Comment: Can you add an image showing the differences?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that `sns.pointplot` simply uses an array of `[0...n-1]` as x values and then uses the x values that you provide to label the ticks on the x-axis. You can check that by looking at `ax.get_xlim()` which outputs `[-0.5, 4.5]`.
Therefore, when you provide the actual x values to `plt.plot` they just seem to be at a wrong position.

I wouldn't say that this is a bug, since seaborn considers the input to `pointplot` to be categorial (here's the [documentation](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.pointplot.html) for more info)

You can solve this for your simple example by mimicking `seaborn`s behavoir:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas
import numpy as np
sns.set_style("white")

data = pandas.DataFrame({"x": [0.158, 0.209, 0.31, 0.4, 0.519],
                        "y": [0.13, 0.109, 0.129, 0.250, 1.10],
                        "s": [0.05]*5})

plt.figure()
sns.pointplot(x="x", y="y", data=data)
plt.errorbar(np.arange(5), data["y"], yerr=data["s"], color='r')
plt.show()
```

[image]